# How can I compose query fragments with variables

Tags: javascript, relayjs

I am using Relay and `react-router-relay` and am trying to compose several Relay containers. The inner container needs a query fragment variable that must be passed from the router down through its parent containers. It's not getting this variable.

Here's how the code looks:

```
//  A "viewer":

const UserQueries = { user: () => Relay.QL`query { user }` };

//  A route to compose a message:

<Route                                                                                                                                                                                  
  path='/compose/:id'                                                                                                                                                                          
  component={ ComposeContainer }                                                                                                                                                               
  queries={ UserQueries }                                                                                                                                                             
/>

//  A container:

const ComposeContainer = Relay.createContainer(
  Compose,
  {
    initialVariables: {
      id: null
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fragments: {                                                                                                                                                                                        
      user: () => Relay.QL`                                                                                                                                                                           
        fragment on User {                                                                                                                                                                          
          ${ BodyContainer.getFragment('user') }                                                                                                                                                           
          // other fragments                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                            
      `                                                                                                                                                                                               
     }
  }
);

//  And the composed container:

const BodyContainer = React.createContainer(
  Body,
  {
    initialVariables: {
      id: null
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fragments: {                                                                                                                                                                                        
      user: () => Relay.QL`                                                                                                                                                                           
        fragment on User {                                                                                                                                                                          
          draft(id: $id) {
            // fields
          }                                                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                                                                            
      `                                                                                                                                                                                               
     }
  }
);
```

The draft field inside `BodyContainer` never gets `$id` from the route param. The signature to [`RelayContainer.getFragment()`](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/3da04fb73dbb8d39f6e12a6e0dd3dce10b69ba88/src/container/RelayContainer.js#L685) has arguments that seem to let you pass params and variables, but I am not sure how this should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `user` fragment on `<ComposeContainer>` has to be something like:

```js
user: ({ id }) => Relay.QL`
  fragment on User {
    ${BodyContainer.getFragment('user', { id })}
    // other fragments
  }
`
```

Additionally, when you compose in `<BodyContainer>` from `<ComposeContainer>`. You'll also need to pass in `id` as a prop, e.g.

```js
<BodyContainer id={this.props.id} />
```

See also additional discussion at https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/309.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it